# Can't send POST request to an old website

Tags: python, asp.net, post, python-requests

I tried different methods for so long to submit a POST request to a form using Python requests but no luck. I'm trying to send `'3513'` to form's text field which has the name `TextTrnNo` and then get the information from the website.

One of my approaches that fails:

```py
import requests

payload = {'TextTrnNo': '3513'}


r = requests.post('https://appiris.infofer.ro/mytrainro.aspx', data=payload)

print(r.text)
```

The output I get:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>
        IRIS Informatii tren
    </title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="train.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><link rel="icon" href="train.ico" type="image/x-icon" />    
        <style type="text/css">
            .style1
            {
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: small;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #006699;
            }
                .style26
                {
                    font-size: small;
                    font-family: Tahoma;
                    color: #003366;
                }
                .style28
            {
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: large;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #006699;
            }
            .style29
            {
                width: 24%;
            }
                .style22
                {
                    font-size: small;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
                .style24
                {
                    width: 162px;
                    color: #336699;
                    font-size: x-small;
                    background-color: #FFFFFF;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    height: 20px;
                }
                .style30
            {
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: small;
                color: #006699;
            }
                .style17
                {
                    color: #336699;
                }
                .style10
                {
                    font-size: small;
                    font-family: Tahoma;
                }
                </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#aec7d2">
        <form method="post" action="mytrainro.aspx" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />


    <script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=JNg0fH_zydENJ7nFcOtvc6yqY25aZ8vD-Ng7zdFvgOejMomgDzr5SQOfJxd86HrHIAnJdwgVKGKwlCLMquTcg919u2vCLYJz5V0xHnmOduOfc5VgeUHRZPW3jweNO1vqw9JZLWTSVL3z295y_EUsB350MMAhbUa41ssYQzHWget11mAeRCd_ANONdJnWqlOV0&amp;t=5854e822" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
    //]]>
    </script>

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="86BE64DB" />
        <p class="style28">
            <img id="Image5" src="Img/icons/flagRO.jpg" />
    &nbsp;CNCF "CFR SA" - IRIS Informatii tren</p>
        <p class="style28">
            <span class="style1">
            <span id="LblError">Servicii IRIS disponibile</span>
            </span>
                </p>
        <div>
            
            
            
            
            <div id="UpdateProgress1" style="display:none;">
        
                    <span class="style26">
                    <img id="Image3" src="Images/Animate/pleasewait_7.gif" height="20" width="22" />
                    &nbsp;</span><span class="style1">Asteptati...</span>
                
    </div>
        <div id="UpdatePanel1">
        
                <span class="style26"><span class="style1">
                <img id="Image4" src="Images/tren.jpg" height="110" width="200" />
                <br />
                </span>
                <span class="style30">Program circulatie</span>
                <span class="style26"><span class="style17">
                <span id="Label1" class="style10">13.01.2019   17:00 -14.01.2019   17:00</span>
                <table class="style29">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="bottom">
                            
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="style26">
                            
                            
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="style26">
                            
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                Numar tren (fără alte caractere suplimentare)</span>
                <input name="TextTrnNo" type="text" maxlength="15" id="TextTrnNo" title="Introduceti numai numărul trenului, fără alte caractere suplimentare" />
                &nbsp;<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Informatii tren" id="Button1" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: small; font-weight: 700; color: #006699; background-color: #FFFFFF" />
                <span id="Lblx" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: small; color: #CC0000"><b><font size="5"></font></b></span>
                <br />
                <br>
                <div>

        </div>
                
                &nbsp;
                <div>

        </div>
                <div>

        </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                
                
                
            
    </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Headers from Google Chrome:

```
    Request URL: https://appiris.infofer.ro/ScriptResource.axd?d=JNg0fH_zydENJ7nFcOtvc6yqY25aZ8vD-Ng7zdFvgOejMomgDzr5SQOfJxd86HrHIAnJdwgVKGKwlCLMquTcg919u2vCLYJz5V0xHnmOduOfc5VgeUHRZPW3jweNO1vqw9JZLWTSVL3z295y_EUsB350MMAhbUa41ssYQzHWget11mAeRCd_ANONdJnWqlOV0&t=5854e822
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 200  (from memory cache)
    Remote Address: 193.230.156.188:443
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
    cache-control: public
    content-encoding: gzip
    content-length: 55951
    content-type: application/x-javascript
    date: Sun, 13 Jan 2019 17:04:19 GMT
    expires: Sun, 12 Jan 2020 22:49:44 GMT
    last-modified: Sat, 12 Jan 2019 22:49:44 GMT
    server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
    status: 200
    x-powered-by: ASP.NET
    Provisional headers are shown
    d: JNg0fH_zydENJ7nFcOtvc6yqY25aZ8vD-Ng7zdFvgOejMomgDzr5SQOfJxd86HrHIAnJdwgVKGKwlCLMquTcg919u2vCLYJz5V0xHnmOduOfc5VgeUHRZPW3jweNO1vqw9JZLWTSVL3z295y_EUsB350MMAhbUa41ssYQzHWget11mAeRCd_ANONdJnWqlOV0
    t: 5854e822
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct as in its sending the post request with the data you want. However, whilst looking at network requests sent to the site, I noticed that there's a couple fields you're missing that prevent the post request from being parsed by the site. These fields being:

- `Button1`
- `__VIEWSTATE`

They can be completely blank, they just have to be part of the post request, thus making your full payload variable:

```py
payload = {'TextTrnNo': '3513', 'Button1': '', '__VIEWSTATE': ''}
```

This returns a different output that includes some sort of table.

Comment: You explained it so well and I understood the problem. Thank you so much for helping 